# What is the difference between fields _source? elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

hi i get my json data then I have a question.

What is the difference between `fields` and `_source`?

Why does Date belong to both `source` and `fields` and not the rest?

Did you do something wrong when you were mapping? overflow is my first time but 'please add some more details' is hard on me.

```
{
  "_index": "nameindex",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "7WRlR20BIPcwc_JrL41I",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "Date": "2019-09-18 11:50:52",
    "@timestamp": "2019-09-19T02:41:14.317Z",
    "input": {},
    "tags": [
      "_dateparsefailure"
    ],
    "ID": "ddd",
    "host": {
      "hostname": "KC20114"
    },
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-09-19T02:41:14.317Z"
    ],
    "Date": [
      "2019-09-18T11:50:52.000Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

this is my index mapping

```
{
  "nameindex" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "host" : {
          "properties" : {
            "hostname" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "input" : {
          "type" : "object"
        },
        "ID" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "Date" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1568860876496",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "D__VED83T7i38Qs3RqlrCQ",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7030099"
        },
        "provided_name" : "nameindex"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it's query

```
PUT /_template/nameindex
{
    "index_patterns": ["nameindex*"],
    "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "host": {
        "properties": {
          "hostname": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "input": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "Date": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      },
      "ID": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

it's json log.
i make this log then filebeat get this automatically

```
{ "userID" : "ddd", "Date" : "2019-09-18 11:50:52" }
```

Comment: between the tags `fields` and `_sources` you mean?

Comment: Can you show your index mapping and your query, please?

Comment: @Olympiloutre yes!

Comment: @Val how could i show u

Comment: Show what you get when running `GET nameindex` + the query you're running to get the document you showed above

Comment: @Val i edit my question! add index mapping and my query

Comment: The query is missing. The last one is your template creation query, I need the one whose endpoint is `_search`

Comment: @Val let me know that how can i change that query

Comment: How do you get the first document you showed?

Comment: @Val oh sorry i miss understand... i just find kibana

Comment: yes, what query did you input in Kibana to find that document?

Comment: @Val i did not input any query just found kibana -> discover -> Expanded document -> json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in `_source` is the actual document that has been indexed, i.e. what Beats sent to your Elasticsearch server. So it contains whatever Beats has captured + some additional fields added by Beats.

What you see in `fields` is what we call [`doc_values`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html), i.e. on-disk data structure, built at document index time, which makes sorting and aggregating on those fields easier and more performant.

By default, in Kibana, the Discover view will always include both the `_source` and [`docvalue_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-docvalue-fields) in the query for all fields of type date. You can see the query being sent by Kibana by clicking on "Inspect" and then on "Request".

Comment: i under stand _source but what is `fields`?

Comment: `fields` contains whatever has been stored in the doc_values index for those two fields, Kibana always asks for doc_values of date fields.

Comment: oh.. u meen `fields` is `docvalue_fields` and it always request a date fields? right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you specify `docvalue_fields` in the query like Kibana does, you'll get the `fields` section in the results.